# Laptop connected to beamer with HDMI = no sound

Tags: audio, hdmi

**Problem:**
I want to connect my laptop to my beamer by HDMI. It shall transmit image and sound. The OS is Win10, no pending updates. The Laptop is 3 years old max, maybe just even 1 or 2.

When connected to the beamer, the picture is fine, but in Windows there is no sound source available, also not at disconnected or disabled devices - so no sound can get transmitted.

When I connect my tower PC (Also Win10) instead, everything works - I get a new sound source (epson blabla) which transmits the sound via HDMI.

I only switched the cable, and checked the sound sources.
Also I tried 3 cables, everytime the same result.
Also I tried already 2 or 3 different Win10 driven Laptops, everytime the same result.

I tried to google it, but 95% of results are "did you select the correct sound source?". Some state to reinstall drivers which I tried, some state to delete some adapters from device manager which I tried. I read often that many people have similar problems when using laptops.

**Question:**
Is it possible that a laptop just can't support sound via HDMI? Like from hardware? Or is this some win10 / laptop / whatsoever issue I might be able to fix (how tho...?)

Comment: It should support audio via HDMI and that is managed by the graphics driver. But Windows 10 not recognizing the HDMI audio device is not unheard of. I'm currently facing the same problem with a miniPC with a Intel Celeron, it works fine in Ubuntu.

Comment: My guess is your laptop can't push enough power from the laptop's hdmi connection to the "beamer" source input in order to transmit the audio. I've ran into this problem myself with older video cards simply connecting to a TV via hdmi.

Comment: @Sickest Unlikely because *in Windows there is no sound source available*. It means the HDMI doesn't appears as a audio device as it should be. The same problem I'm having as commented above and has nothing to do with the hardware or power because it works in Ubuntu in the same miniPC. (Note: In Device Manager manager it shows "Intel audio for displays" along with the Realtek sound card but not in the sound settings as output device, so it's a Windows thing exclusively).

Comment: The laptop is my work laptop, more powerful than many PCs ... Can't imagine that it comes down to a problem of power. I read several hours on google etc. and can't find one solution or even clarification explaining why it can't be done. I hoped some one here could be the savior :P Until then I search ahead, I need to fix this as it's rather for guests of mine insead of myself, and it kinda sucks. Thanks so far!